# Coded UI Test not working with 64 bit application

Tags: c#, .net, coded-ui-tests

I have created a coded UI solution, and referenced this in another application which is running as 64 bit process.Now when I run this coded UI test with this application it throws an exception saying at

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException(COMException innerException, IPlaybackContext context)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception exception, IPlaybackContext context)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.Initialize()

However when I run the same application as a 32 bit process it works fine to me, Can anyone have idea of this

I am using Visual studio 2015 and running application in 4.6.2 framework.

I am getting error in below code(highlighted).

```
if(!Playback.IsInitialized) {
    Playback.Initialize();
    Playback.PlaybackSettings.LoggerOverrideState = HtmlLoggerState.Disabled;
}
```